# VBA to copy sheets without changing the format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question regarding my code that somehow changes the format (row height and column width) when I copy some sheets to another workbook - this is used as a middle step before printing to pdf. In the sheets "1", "2" and "3" the sheets are set up with a print area that only cover one A4 page, but when the code copies the selected sheets to a new temporary workbook all rows and columns have increased (increased pixels) so that the print area now covers several pages. Can anyone help?

```
Sub Print_to_pdf()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Output_Sheets = Sheets(Array("1", "2", "3"))

Output_Sheets.Select
Output_Sheets.Copy

ChDir "XXX"
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "XXX\Print_to_pdf".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried saving an exact copy, removing the unnecessary sheets and then print to PDF. Of course, this is a bit more cumbersome but at the same time this should (almost certainly) keep the formats.

Comment: Yes, this works, but the code is part of a sequence of codes that combined saves 10-20 different pdf's with different sheets, so printing to pdf "the old way" will cause the process to take way to long. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: It's not really clear but do you export the copied sheets or the original sheets? If you export the copied sheets: Did you try to export the original sheets with that code? I could imagine that the issue is not in the copy action but an inaccurate export. I'm used to that exporting sheets results in a different result than printing sheets (due to inaccurate pdf export engines).

Comment: I have an original workbook with the sheets "1", "2" and "3". With the code "Output_Sheets.copy" VBA creates a new temporary workbook which is then saved as a pdf. But if this step is not necessary, then I am open to another way of saving as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why you tried to copy those sheets. To export the sheets you could simply use this:

```
Sub Print_to_pdf()
    Dim Output_Sheets As Sheets

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Output_Sheets = Sheets(Array("1", "2", "3"))
    Output_Sheets.Select

    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "c:\temp\Print_to_pdf.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If there are differences between the exported PDF file and any printers then this is probably due to differences in printer drivers and the PDF export engine. The only way I see to solve this playing around until it fits on both (printer and export).